# Find html tags in a second #document doctype HTML with selenium and python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

So, with python and selenium I'm trying to scrape a website with a structure I have not seen before. There is a doctype html inside the main one, and when I try to get an element from the second one, my browser can't reach it.

```
slip=browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"-BetslipWebModule ")]')
data=slip.find_element_by_id('betslipContainer')

>>NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="betslipContainer"]"}
```

If I try to print what is inside slip tag, there is nothing there of this second document inside

```
slip.get_attribute('outerHTML')
'<div class="bw-BetslipWebModule "><div class="bw-BetslipHeader "><div class="bw-BetslipHeader_Item bw-BetslipHeader_Item-active ">Cupón de apuestas</div></div><div class="bw-BetslipWebModule_FrameContainer " style="height: 238px;"><iframe src="https://www.bet365.es/betslip/WebInterface/BsInterface.aspx?v=1815" name="bsFrame" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="false" class="bw-BetslipWebModule_Frame " style="height: 238px;"></iframe></div></div>'
```

My question would be, how can I have access to the code inside #document if with my regular browser there is no path I know of which enables me to do so?

[image: HTML Structure]

Comment: To read a document inside an iframe, just take the frame's src and read that.